# Flask post parsing data variables

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm using AJAX to send data in a POST to Flask, however the POST data that I'm getting is not something my skills can parse. Can someone help me try and understand how I can parse these variables into perhaps a list?

The data seen in Flask looks like this:

`items%5B%5D=104-92923-G42LH&items%5B%5D=102-10001-CRD-P07G19&items%5B%5D=104-92925-SML-CLRH&items%5B%5D=104-92923-92R-LH&items%5B%5D=104-92924-COLTRH`

When I decode it with a online decoder, then I see:

`items[]=104-92923-G42LH&items[]=102-10001-CRD-P07G19&items[]=104-92925-SML-CLRH&items[]=104-92923-92R-LH&items[]=104-92924-COLTRH`

My problem is, I have no idea how to parse this string into a list. I have used differnet `request` functions to see if I can get the data presented some other way, but still I have no luck. Currently I'm using `data = request.stream.read()` in my flask function to get see the data.

Also, here is my AJAX function:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
            var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/_data";
            var result = [];
                $('.varSku').each(function () {
                result.push($(this).data("sku"));
                });
            var data1 = {items: result};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType : "string",
                data: data1,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                }
                });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

My Flask function:

```
@app.route('/_data', methods=['GET','POST'])
def invoice():
    data = request.stream.read()
    print data.decode('utf8') 
    return "data"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when sending POST data containing values that are arrays or objects, jQuery follows a PHP convention of adding brackets to the field names.

To get past it, I had to use another function called [`MultiDict.getlist()`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) and therefore I had to change to `request.form.getlist("items[]")`

Thanks for the help @Martin

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `request.form`, it automatically parses the body content into a dictionary. In your case you should use `request.form["items"]`.

Check the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#accessing-request-data) for more information.

Comment: when I change to `request.form['items']` as you suggested, I get an empty dict `items[]`.